# Accessing Azure Virtual machine behind proxy / firewwall

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, firewall

I have created a Windows 2016 data center on Microsoft Azure cloud. I also downloaded its RDP file. However, when I am trying to access it from my Organization I get below error. (of course, organization uses proxy/firewall). When I access it from my home internet, I can access the VM successfully.

[image]

Currently the networking of the VM has below setting:

[image]

Please help to access the azure VM via proxy.

**Edit:**
Got few great answers. However, being a trainer, I need to keep creating and deleting the VMs on day to day basis, hence requesting network admin to add a particular VM IP to exception list won't help. Is there any other way possible?

Comment: Could you contact your network admin to add the inbound rule to that proxy?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Please elaborate and help me understanding...

Comment: can you telnet port 3389 of that VM?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Telnet is not installed on my machine. Tried installing, but its not allowed by organization.

Comment: @AdityaBokade Hi. Did you find a solution for your issue? I am facing the issue, working behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Go with Jason's suggestion. Your network admin needs to configure the corresponding rules for the firewall or proxy. What you need to tell the network admin depends on your setup:

- If you are dealing with one VM only, then you could either configure the public IP that is assigned to the VM as static and ask the network admin to allow rdp to that IP address, or, alternatively,
- if you would like to save [costs for the public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) and your organisation's proxy/firewall is capable of working with DNS names, then you could assign a DNS name to the public IP and let the network admin know the DNS name. The DNS name would be something similar to this: ***myazurevmname*.*azurelocation*.cloudapp.azure.com**

If you are planning to access several VM's in Azure, you can either repeat above steps for each of the VM's, however, may want to think about establishing a point-to-site VPN from your local computer which would remove the need for assigning public IP addresses to each of the VM's. The network setup in Azure will be more complex upfront, but it may be worth the effort. However, this will be a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up teamviewer as a service(!) on your VM and then connect to it with teamviewer from your company pc. it'll be a bit laggy but you'll get used to it
[Use this tutorial to set up teamviewer](http://www.appdataworks.com/how-to-set-up-teamviewer-to-allow-remote-control-even-with-no-user-signed-in-to-windows/)

Comment: Thanks for amazing idea! But unfortunately, TeamViewer is not allowed to be used in the network of my organization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your organization network block it, you should contact your network admin to **add** it to firewall/proxy.

Comment: Please let me know what details need to be applied  to the firewall, that i need to convey it to my network admin? Also, once is it added, will it be applicable to any VM of Azure? I remember I had request my network team to add *.azurewebsites.net and they had done it. Is it possible for all/any VM of azure?

Comment: @AdityaBokade Yes, we should add your VM's public IP address to your firewall, if you want to connect to all Azure VMs, maybe you should add Azure public IP addresses to your firewall.

Comment: @AdityaBokade we can download the IP range [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=41653).

Comment: @AdityaBokade can you connect to that VM now?